# How to create 3 levels form with data-prototypes symfony 2.8

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have 3 entites: ( CV, DomaineCompetence and Competences) 
CV can have many DomaineCompetence and DomaineCompetence can have many Competences, and each entity have a formType.

**Cv Entity**

```
class Cv
{ 
 //...

  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="DomaineCompetenceCv", mappedBy="cv", cascade={"persist"})
   * 
   */
   private $domainesCompetence;
```

**DomaineCompetence Entity**

```
class DomaineCompetenceCv
{
 /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cv", inversedBy="domainesCompetence")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cv_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $cv;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompetenceCv", mappedBy="domaineCompetence", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 */
private $competences;
```

**CompetenceCv**

```
class CompetenceCv
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="niveau", type="integer")
 */
private $niveau;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DomaineCompetenceCv", inversedBy="competences")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="domaine_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $domaineCompetence;
```

**CVForm**

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{ $builder
    //...
    ->add('domainesCompetence', CollectionType::class, array(

        'entry_type' => DomaineCompetenceCvForm::class,
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'by_reference' => false,


    ))      
        ;

}
```

**DomaineCompetenceCvForm**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')
            ->add('competences', CollectionType::class, array(

        'entry_type' => CompetenceCvForm::class,
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'by_reference' => true,


    ))      
            ;
}
```

**CompetencesCvForm**

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')->add('niveau')    ;
}
```

**Twig for Cv**

```
 <form role="form" action="" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
                             {{ form_widget(form._token) }}  
    //...
     <h4 class="no-margin-top has-divider text-highlight">Compétences</h4>
             <div id="domaineCV" class="domaineCV" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.domainesCompetence.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">

                 {% for com in form.domainesCompetence %}

                   <div class="" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(com.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">

                   </div>
                   {% endfor %}
               </div>
   </form>
```

I use javaScript to add more than DomaineCompetence but the problem is that the form of Competence does not display

Someone can help me please ? thanks for all.

[image: twig render]
**JS for domainesCompetence**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

var $container = $('div#domaineCV');


var $addLink = $('<a href="#" id="add_category" class="btn btn-default">Ajouter une Domaine de compétence</a>');
$container.append($addLink);


$addLink.click(function(e) {
  addCategory($container);
  e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
  return false;
});


var index = $container.find(':input').length;


if (index == 0) {
  addCategory($container);
} else {

  $container.children('div').each(function() {
    addDeleteLink($(this));
  });
}


function addCategory($container) {

  var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Catégorie n°' + (index+1))
      .replace(/__name__/g, index));


  addDeleteLink($prototype);


  $container.append($prototype);

  index++;
}


function addDeleteLink($prototype) {

  $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');


  $prototype.append($deleteLink);


  $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
    $prototype.remove();
    e.preventDefault(); =
    return false;
  });
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in my local environment, same stack (Symfony 2.8.20)

From your screenshot, I can see that DomainesCompetence form is displayed inside Cv form because of the js you created to handle this collection. But are you sure that the actual js handle the **competences** collection inside each **DomaineCompetence** form?

And maybe you will need to [customize your CompetenceCvType collection prototype](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype). Please give a feedback.

** Edit: dirty solution (work but need refactor !!!)**

First point, DomaineCompetence (embedded inside you Cv form) form prototype is populated when you render your Cv form template but the embedded Competence form prototype is not populated in your DomaineCompetence form. You can populate the second level form collection in your controller like this :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\CvType;
use AppBundle\Form\DomaineCompetenceCvType;
use AppBundle\Form\CompetenceCvType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class CvController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/new")
     */
     public function newAction()
     {
         $form = $this->createForm(CvType::class);
         $domaineCompetenceCvForm = $this
             ->createForm(
                 CompetenceCvType::class,
                 null,
                 array('auto_initialize' => false
             )
         );
         $form->get('domainesCompetence')
             ->add($domaineCompetenceCvForm)
         ;


         return $this->render(
             ':cv:new.html.twig',
             array(
                 'form' => $form->createView(),
             )
         );
    }
}
```

Next update your template like this :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _appbundle_cv_domainesCompetence_entry_widget %}
    {{ form_row(form.nom) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}AppBundle:Cv:new{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Welcome to the Cv:new page</h1>

    <form role="form" action="" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
        {{ form_widget(form._token) }}  

        <h4 class="no-margin-top has-divider text-highlight">Compétences</h4>
        Domaines
        <div style="border: 1px solid green" id="domaineCV" class="domaineCVs" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.domainesCompetence.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">

            <div style="border: 1px solid yellow" id="competencesProto" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.children.domainesCompetence)|e('html_attr') }}">
            </div>
        </div>


    </form> 
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }} {# load your jquery and bootstrap deps #}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {# custom js handling your collections here #}
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Then this is the js :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $prototype = '';
    var $container = $('div#domaineCV');
    var $competencesContainer = '';
    var $competencesProtoContainer = $('div#competencesProto');

    var $addLink = $('<a href="#" id="add_category" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter une Catégorie</a>');
    var $addCompetence = $('<a href="#" id="add_competence" class="btn btn-warning">Ajouter une compétence</a>');
    $container.after($addLink);


    $addLink.click(function(e) {
        addCategory($container);
        e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
        return false;
    });

    $addCompetence.click(function(e) {
        addCompetence($competencesContainer);
        e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
        return false;
    });


    var index = $container.find(':input').length;
    var competencesIndex = 0;

    if (index == 0) {
        addCategory($container);
        competencesIndex = $competencesContainer.find(':input').length; 
    } else {
        $container.children('div').each(function() {
          addDeleteLink($(this));
        });
    }

    function addCategory($container) {

        $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Catégorie n°' + (index+1))
            .replace(/__name__/g, index));
        $container.prepend($prototype);
         $competencesContainer = $('div#competencesProto');
        $competencesContainer.after($addCompetence);   

        addCompetence($competencesContainer);

        addDeleteLink($prototype);

        index++;
    }

    function addCompetence($competencesContainer) {
        var $competenceProto = $($competencesProtoContainer.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Catégorie n°' + (competencesIndex+1))
          .replace(/__name__/g, competencesIndex));

      $competencesContainer.append($competenceProto);
      $prototype.append($competenceProto);
  
      addCompetenceDeleteLink($competenceProto);

      competencesIndex++;
    }

    function addDeleteLink($element) {
        $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer catégorie</a>');

        $element.append($deleteLink);


        $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
            $element.remove();
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false;
        });
    }

    function addCompetenceDeleteLink($element) {

        $deleteCompetenceLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer competence</a>');

        $element.append($deleteCompetenceLink);


        $deleteCompetenceLink.click(function(e) {
          $element.remove();
          e.preventDefault(); 
          return false;
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the DomainesCompetence form is displayed only for the name(nom) but the collection of Competences in this domaine does not displayed

Comment: That's what I am talking about. Check if your js also handle the collection of Competences. Maybe the js handle some CSS classes used the DomainesCompetence form but not CSS classes used in the collection of Competences. Can I see your js to completely reproduce your issue ?

Comment: I edit the question to add my script js , I also think that the problem is in script js. but i'm from 2 weeks in same problem and i cant found solution :(

Comment: Someone can help me please ? I'm tried to develop an application for my Preject of End Studies, and i'm really blocked :( .. thanks a lot

Comment: @DhiaEddineFarah I updated my post with a working solution. This should do the trick but very dirty. Maybe you should Try to do another application design for this problem.